# Fiddler request converted to jQuery Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, fiddler

Is there anyway to grab a POST or GET request out of Fiddler and have it converted to a jQuery AJAX request?

I would write the AJAX request but I am still trying to wrap my head around it all, and in the mean time I need some assistance.. :/

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: There's no direct way, but if you know the URL of the request, it's method and the data in fiddler it's only 5 lines of code to write in jQuery - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: For GET at least, it's just a url.   To make the ajax call, you can do: `$.ajax('*url*', { success: function(data) { alert(data); });`

Comment: also worth noting that fiddler is not under same CORS restrictions as browsers for cross domain requests